# Implementing extensible search query in Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, string, post, mysqli

I am trying to migrate to Mysqli and I got my Mysql code to search for parameters like this:

```
$querySt = "SELECT userID FROM myTable";
if (isset($_POST["UserID"])) {
    if (ctype_digit($_POST["UserID"])) {
        addWhereIfNoHave();
        $in_userID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["UserID"]);
        $querySt .= " UserID = '$in_userID'";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
    addWhereIfNoHave();
    $in_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);    
    $querySt .= " imgName LIKE LOWER('%$in_name%')";
}

if (isset($_POST["ScoreLessThan"])) {
    if (ctype_digit($_POST["ScoreLessThan"])) {
        addWhereIfNoHave();
        $in_ScoreLessThan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ScoreLessThan"]);
        $querySt .= " Score < '$in_ScoreLessThan'";
    }           
}

...
...
there are other if statements here looking for other post data, and 
they keep on adding parameters into mysql query string just like above.
...
...

//this function is called in those if statements above. It either adds "WHERE" or "AND".
function addWhereIfNoHave(){
    global $querySt;
    if (strpos($querySt, 'WHERE') !== false){
        $querySt .= " OR";  
        return true;
    }else{
        $querySt .= " WHERE";
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function works ok looking for all the parameters input from PHP post. However, I am migrating this to Mysqli, and I have a bit of trouble converting this code to Mysqli version. For example,

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userID FROM myTable WHERE UserID = ? AND name= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $userid, $name);
```

Suppose, I wanna search the table using 2 variables, I bind 2 variables like above, but in the case of my Mysql above, I keep on extending additional parameters into the string before executing the mysql query.

But for Mysqli, how can we do this? Is it possible to `bind` additional parameters and extending the string for `prepare` statement like Mysql code above? How should this problem be approach for Mysqli?

My current problem is mainly with the bind_param. I could concatenate the search query further and add all the '?' into the prepare statement, but with different variable types and number variables needed to be specified in bind_param, this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Please review this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546631/mysql-php-select-a-record-thats-similar-to-another/42548470#42548470)

Comment: @AmrAly I see you concatenate the string further similarly to what I am doing above. But isn't the point of using bind_param is so that you don't put PHP variable directly into the query, preventing something like SQL injection?

Comment: yes i got it you could review this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961401/dynamic-variables-binding-in-mysqli-bind-param)